# Range Partitioning in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Does hive support range partitioning?

I mean does hive supports something like below:

```
insert overwrite table table2 PARTITION (employeeId BETWEEN 2001 and 3000) 
select employeeName FROM emp10 where employeeId BETWEEN 2001 and 3000;
```

Where table2 & emp10 has two columns:

employeeName &
employeeId

When I run the above query i am facing an error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:56 mismatched input 'BETWEEN' expecting ) near 'employeeId' in destination specification
```

Answer (score 2):

Is not possible. Here is a quote from [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) :

> A table can have one or more partition columns and a separate data directory is created for **each distinct value combination** in the partition columns

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible. Even I use separate calculated column like ,

`insert overwrite table table2 PARTITION (employeeId_range) 
select employeeName , employeeId/1000 FROM emp10 where employeeId BETWEEN 2000 and 2999;`

which will make sure all values fall in same partition.
while querying the table since we already know the range calculator, we can

`select employeeName , employeeId FROM table2 where employeeId_range=2;`

Thus we can also parallelise the queries of given ranges.
Hope it helps.